# C# database classes to change between postgres and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql

I am overthinking this and can't find the right terms to search on in Google.

I have a website that connects to a SQL Server database with mostly centralized classes to call out to the database.

I was able to copy/paste those classes and tweak them to connect to a postgres db by simple changes like changing:

This for connections

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionManagerToUse); 
PgSqlConnection connection = new PgSqlConnection(ConnectionManagerToUse);
```

and this for commands:

```
SqlCommand SelectDataCommand = new SqlCommand();                        
PgSqlCommand SelectDataCommandPostgres = new PgSqlCommand();
```

This worked great so far by changing all instances of the above. I want to see if there is a way to have a class or something that is middle man that I can call to change between these 2 in the code so I only have to change code in this middle function to change between Postgres and SQL Server and not everywhere I call out to these commands in my code (obviously specific SQL calls and SQL syntax would be different but I am looking for ways to update the underlying code calling out to the database, not the actual SQL syntax).

Something like the below. I would call this instead of the above (I know this does not work this is just for example) then if I want to change database technology I just change it with a single variable or something in this centralized class/config files (or even have ability to connect to 2 different databases with different technologies at once.

For connections example:

```
public T GetConnection<T>()
{ 
    if (_DBTechnology == "MSSQL")
    {
        return new SqlConnection(_connectionStringMSSQL);
    }
    else if (_DBTechnology == "POSTGRES")
    {
        return new PgSqlConnection(_connectionStringPostgres));
    }        
}
```

I know the above is not valid and I have only used generics a few times so this may not be the way to do this at all. So any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The connection classes derives from DbConnection so your method should return that type. But in the end simply exchanging all databases classes (commands, readers etc.) with their baseclasses and working against them doesn't normally work out. You will run in behavioral problems like slighty different sql syntax. Different database types etc. If you haven't written your system with beeing standard conforming  in the first place don't do it.

Comment: Use some kind of repository pattern that returns your data in a database neutral way (POCOs) and only use the distinct database classes inside the (exchangeable) repository classes for the different db brands.

Comment: @Ralf Yea For specific SQL queries and syntax I know that part would not work across them but all the creating commands/connections/data sets/etc  are all generic and should be able to work.  Just when executing actual SQL code I would not be able to use generics like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with solution for this.  Below is the basic code to do what I was looking to do.  I am working on expanding for more versitiality and usability for multile scenerios but this covers the basics.

This works because the classes/methods for both SQL server and Postgres work similar/the same.

The drivers I used for the Postgres were Devart.Data ande Devart.Data.PostgresSql (found through Nuget)

```
// set variable for db to use.  Classes use MS  for sql server, and PG for Postgres
string DBToUse = "MS";  //"PG"  for Postgres

// Call to get the empty connection
DbConnection connection = GetConnection(DBToUse)

//Call the class to create empty connection:
DbCommand SelectDataCommandToBuild = GetCommand(DBToUse);




// here are classes to call to get the correct DB connections
public static DbConnection GetConnection(string DBToUse)
{
    DbConnection connection = null;

    if (DBToUse == "MS")
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionStringMSSQL);

    }
    else if (DBToUse == "PG")
    {
        connection = new PgSqlConnection(_connectionStringPostgres);
    }
    

    // default just return null
    return connection;
}// generic SQL Connection

public static DbCommand GetCommand(string DBToUse)
{            
    DbCommand command = null;

    if (DBToUse == "MS")
    {
        command = new SqlCommand();

    }
    else if (DBToUse == "PG")
    {
        command = new PgSqlCommand();
    }


    // default just return null
    return command;
}// generic SQL Command
```